# How to keep stable positions in BaseAdapter.getView for created views?

Tags: android

it seems to be a problem keeping positions for already created views in BaseAdapter.getView().

In my case I've created an data-object(-array) holding all my data for a listview. There are three types of listitems: seperators, items with checkbox and items with an clickable image to open a dialog. That data will performed by a customized array-adapter, always with a separate layout. For that I used different viewholders. Creation is not the problem, but if the recycler starts it's work all indizes/positions are changed. But on that indizes my data are based on.

I know how the recycler works, but how (in hell) the programmer should keep the relation to it's own data?

Here in stackoverflow.com some people asked the same questions, and the answer was 'override getItemViewType-Methode'. No problem, but if position always changes, that not really helps, right?

Have someone a solution?

Regards
Pierre

**Here's my proove of concept code:**

```
// *** Activity: onCreate()

...
ArrayList<DataObj> data = getData();

    final ListView list = (ListView)findViewById( R.id.listView1 );
    list.setAdapter( new PackedListAdapter( this, data ) );
...

// *** Activity: getData()

private ArrayList<DataObj> getData() {
ArrayList<DataObj> dataArr = new ArrayList<DataObj>();
DataObj dataset;
int i;

dataset = new DataObj();
dataset.setType( DataObj.TYPE_CATEGORY );
dataset.setItemText( "Category CheckItems" );
dataArr.add( dataset );

for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
            dataset = new DataObj();
    dataset.setType( DataObj.TYPE_ITEM_CHECK );
    dataset.setItemText( "ItemCheck #" + i );
    dataArr.add( dataset );
}

dataset = new DataObj();
dataset.setType( DataObj.TYPE_CATEGORY );
dataset.setItemText( "Category DialogItems" );
dataArr.add( dataset );

for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
     dataset = new DataObj();
    dataset.setType( DataObj.TYPE_ITEM_DLG );
    dataset.setItemText( "ItemDlg #" + i );
    dataArr.add( dataset );
}

return dataArr;
}

// *** Data-Object:

public class DataObj {
private int type = 1;
// further variables here (e.g. String text1 ) ...

public final static int TYPE_CATEGORY = 1;
public final static int TYPE_ITEM_CHECK = 2;
public final static int TYPE_ITEM_DLG = 3;

public void setType( int type ) { this.type = type; }
public int getType() { return type; }

// further setter/getter-methodes for variables here ...
}

// *** BaseAdapter:

public class PackedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static ArrayList<DataObj> mData;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

PackedListAdapter( Context context, ArrayList<DataObj> data ) {
    mData = data;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
}

public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

public Object getItem( int position ) {
    return mData.get( position );
}

public long getItemId( int position ) { return position; }

public int getItemViewType( int position ) { 
    return mData.get( position ).getType();
}

public boolean hasStableIds() { return false; }

public int getViewTypeCount() { return 3; }

public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
    int type = this.getItemViewType( position );

    if ( convertView == null ) {
        switch ( type ) {
            case DataObj.TYPE_CATEGORY:
            {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate( R.layout.listcat, null );
                ViewHolderCat holder = new ViewHolderCat();
                // setting up data from mData(position) here
                convertView.setTag( holder );
                break;
            }
            case DataObj.TYPE_ITEM_CHECK:
            {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate( R.layout.listrow, null );
                ViewHolderItem holder = new ViewHolderItem();
                // setting up data from mData(position) here
                convertView.setTag( holder );
                break;
            }
            case DataObj.TYPE_ITEM_DLG:
            {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate( R.layout.listdlg, null );
                ViewHolderDlg holder = new ViewHolderDlg();
                // setting up data from mData(position) here
                convertView.setTag( holder );
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        switch ( type ) {
            case DataObj.TYPE_CATEGORY:
            {
                ViewHolderCat holder = (ViewHolderCat)convertView.getTag();
                // setting up data from mData(position) here
                break;
            }
            case DataObj.TYPE_ITEM_CHECK:
            {
                ViewHolderItem holder = (ViewHolderItem)convertView.getTag();
                // setting up data from mData(position) here
                break;
            }
            case DataObj.TYPE_ITEM_DLG:
            {
                ViewHolderDlg holder = (ViewHolderDlg)convertView.getTag();
                // setting up data from mData(position) here
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolderCat {
    public TextView txtCat;
}

public static class ViewHolderItem {
    public TextView txtItem;
    public TextView txtDescr;
    public ImageView imgCheckButton;
}

public static class ViewHolderDlg {
    public TextView txtItem;
    public TextView txtDescr;
    public ImageView imgDlgButton;
}

}
```

Comment: As you mentioned you can't keep positions for views because the views are re-used. What exactly are you trying to do that requires knowing the positions?

Comment: Hi Robby, imagine you have to vectors. One is your datasetlist and one is your viewlist. If you copy your data-vector to viewlist now (like in baseadapter) each new created view points to a dataset (dependend on it's position in datasetlist). But because of recyclers work positions/indizes change, so that view #0 with dataset #0 now is view #9 with dataset #9 for instance. So originally view #0 is a separator at start of list and view #9 is a checkbox item at end of list under another separator. Now it's positions/contents are changed. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

You should override [hasStableIds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#hasStableIds%28%29) in addition to [getItemViewType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) and [getViewTypeCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29). This will look something like:

```
@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    /* the view types for rows will change over time */
    return false;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    /* calculate the view type for this row */
    return ... ;
}
```

I believe this lets the framework know it shouldn't do caching based on the item id.

Comment: Hi Matthew, nice idea, but it don't helps. The problem by this position-shifting is, that the predefined view-types holded in my data-object after a shifting not match anymore. The error which occurs is a ClassCastException of course than. (It's crazy: the hole thing is so easy, but that silly behaviour makes me mad.)

Comment: You probably need to post your code. You shouldn't be keeping a list of your view objects, just the model objects. The list of view objects is maintained by the `ListView` and updated according to your `getView` method.

Answer (score 1):

The solution seems to be a BaseAdapter which contains further adapters...

http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to create a local cache of my Views that relates to my data set recently, but after watching this I decided to give up:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&feature=player_detailpage#t=816s

If the ListView developers suggest to not do this, I felt like I should heed their advice and not try to hack it.

Comment: Do it, but I never give up. I know it works and now it's time to find out how ...